# Designing class hierarchy - multiple inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am aware that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. But if I have to design a class system for say, Animal kingdom. How to represent animals that are hybrids of two different animals? For ex, a Mule (Donkey or Horse?), a Liger (Lion or Tiger). How to inherit both Lion and Tiger classes to make a Liger class? 
Is there a way of doing it without making Tiger and Lion as interfaces? What if they cannot be made interfaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inheritance is not the right tool to use in this case. You see, a liger is *not* a tiger, and neither it is a lion. It *has* characteristics of both, but it *is* neither.

Say you go to a zoo and the cage says "Tiger". You peek in and see this weird gigantic cat that you certainly do not recognize as a tiger. [It's cool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger), but not a tiger. You also don't think it's a lion. It's not [substitutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for either.

So, it should *compose* a `Lion` and a `Tiger` and *delegate* its behavior to the right one, or "override" their behaviors completely or partially.

**UPDATE:**

Now, what to do if you really want some kind of multiple inheritance, like if you want to derive a `Liger` from both a `Hybrid` and a `Feline`? Take a look at [Scala traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126) for a possibility. To implement it in Java, you'd need an interface and a class for each concept in the design that you want to multiply "inherit". Take a look [here](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/03/scala-traits-under-hood.html) for the idea.

Comment: Nice explanation! Its much more clear now how to handle such scenarios. I am not very familiar with the delegation and composition concepts but will definitely dig in and learn. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

They'll always need to be interfaces *iff* you want a single object to be identifiable as both.

You can often delegate behavior to composited classes, but in the case of the liger (it's pretty much my favorite subclass), you'd need to decide which animal's behavior will have priority. A liger might be a direct descendant of one or the other, or neither.

Java only allows multiple "API inheritance" (interfaces), not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, it is impossible. Plus it also could be a sign of a bad design (as it might bring ambiguity even if it were possible). So, you might have to try to avoid it and rethink your design.

Comment: Whether or not it brings ambiguity depends on what's being subclassed.

Comment: IMHO, in case of Liger, it's very likely to bring ambiguity.

Comment: Sure, but it always depends on what's being subclassed, and the classes' behaviors. My point was that saying it's a sign of bad design is a sweeping generalization that I don't believe can be reliably asserted.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple class inheritance. Consider the functions that "Lion" and "Tiger" might have in common. Java didn't want to solve the "function collision" problem:

```
class Lion{
    public String call(){
        return "ROAR";
    }
}
class Tiger{
    public String call(){
        return "growl";
    }
}
class Liger extends Lion, Tiger{
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(new Liger().call());
}
```

What should be printed?

Java does not support multiple class inheritance, so this doesn't work- the "extends Lion, Tiger" portion of the class declaration is illegal. Java supports a disambiguation mechanic for interfaces, but this wasn't extended to classes.

Your best bet is to convert *every* animal class into an interface, and then convert the code into implementations of those interfaces. A Liger could be implemented as follows:

```
interface Liger extends Lion, Tiger { }
class LigerImpl implements Liger{
    private Lion mom;
    private Tiger dad;
    public LigerImpl(){
        mom = new LionImpl();
        dad = new TigerImpl();
    }
    public String call(){
        if(math.random() > 0.5){
            return mom.call();
        } else {
            return dad.call();
    }
}
```

This approach requires explicit delegation to each of the underlying implementations; absolutely nothing happens "for free". Java won't get you any closer, though. Java's design throughout pretty much boils down to "if anything is in any way ambiguous, unsafe, undefined, or could potentially cause a type or parse conflict, make the programmer write more code."

Answer (score 0):

I am ***NOT*** recommending you do this, but reflection could work. Of course using "instanceof" will never work...

```
public class Lion {
    public void roar() {
        System.out.println("Lion is roaring");
    }

    public void eat(String what) {
        System.out.println("Lion is eating " + what);
    }
}

public class Tiger {
    public void purr() {
        System.out.println("Tiger is purring");
    }

    public void eat(String what) {
        System.out.println("Tiger is eating " + what);
    }
}

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Liger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Liger liger = new Liger();
        liger.purr();
        liger.roar();
        liger.eat("food");

        //Result
        //Tiger is purring
        //Lion is roaring
        //Tiger is eating food
        //Lion is eating food
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> _extends = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public Liger() {
        _extends.add(new Tiger());
        _extends.add(new Lion());
    }

    private void invoke(String methodName, Object... args) {
        for ( Object obj : _extends ) {
            Class cls = obj.getClass();
            Method[] methods = cls.getMethods();
            for ( Method m : methods ) {
                if ( m.getName().equals(methodName) ) {
                    try {
                        m.invoke(obj, args);
                    }
                    catch ( Exception ex ) {
                        //handle me
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void purr() {
        invoke("purr"); //Tiger only
    }

    public void roar() {
        invoke("roar"); // Lion only
    }

    public void eat(String what) {
        invoke("eat", what); //Both
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just an ugly, unreliable way of doing delegation.